# Using PHP POST vars as associative array by supplying array keys in POST var names

Tags: php, associative-array

PHP devs know that fields with [] appended to the name will produce an array of values.  For example

```
<input type="hidden" name="gift[]" value="Jerry Garciuh" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[]" value="Gulf South Thingamabob" />
```

Will produce

```
Array
(
    [gift] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jerry Garciuh
            [2] => Gulf South Thingamabob
        )

)
```

But I recently learned this can be taken a step farther:

Comment: If you intended to answer your own question that's cool, but you might want to rephrase it to look more like a question.

Comment: It was new to me and the question form has option "answer this question Q & A style"

Answer (score 3):

Is that something new? O.o
At around 2003 I used this way to make 4-6 dimensions array to save settings for cms

Answer (score 2):

By supplying key values in the field names like so:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="gr" >
<input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="foobarbaz" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[amount]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[recipient_email]" value="jerrygarciuh@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[recipient_name]" value="Jerry Garciuh" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[sender_name]" value="Gulf South Thingamabob" />
<input type="hidden" name="gift[message_announce]" value="Oh hai" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can produce more highly organized associative arrays of post data for your back end:

```
Array
(
    [api_key] => foobarbaz
    [gift] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 1
            [recipient_email] => jerrygarciuh@example.com
            [recipient_name] => Jerry Garciuh
            [sender_name] => Gulf South Thingamabob
            [message_announce] => Oh hai
        )

)
```

Comment: You still have to filter each part of the array, which greatly cuts down on any efficiency gained, unless they're all of the same type.  If they were all strings, for instance, you could do `$gift = filter_var_array($_POST['gift'], array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));`.